# Using json_encode for Google graph display

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, echo

I am trying to import data from a PHP array to a JS google line graph... Once I can figure out how to `echo` the results, I will be able to finish it. The results are meant to look like this:

```
data.addRows([
        [new Date(2014, 0),  -.5,  5.7],
        [new Date(2014, 1),   .4,  8.7],
        [new Date(2014, 2),   .5,   12],
        [new Date(2014, 3),  2.9, 15.3],
        [new Date(2014, 4),  6.3, 18.6],
        [new Date(2014, 5),    9, 20.9],
        [new Date(2014, 6), 10.6, 19.8],
        [new Date(2014, 7), 10.3, 16.6],
        [new Date(2014, 8),  7.4, 13.3],
        [new Date(2014, 9),  4.4,  9.9],
        [new Date(2014, 10), 1.1,  6.6],
        [new Date(2014, 11), -.2,  4.5]
      ]);
```

I currently am using `JSON_ENCODE` for an array like this:

```
$data = array("[new Date(2014, 0),  -.5,  5.7],', '[new Date(2014, 1),   .4,  8.7],");
    json_encode($data);
```

Which I will be able to use to pull data from my database eventually and I am trying to echo the results like this:

```
 data.addRows([
        <?
         echo str_replace('"', '', json_encode($data));
        ?>
    ]);
```

The problem is, nothing is working? Does anybody know what I may be doing wrong here?

Comment: Why would you remove all the quotes, that makes it invalid javascript

Comment: Also, why on earth would you echo function calls from PHP, just get the timestamps on the server

Comment: You cannot use `Date` objects inside of JSON (unless they're first initialized in PHP and serialized to a string), in fact, you can only use plain objects inside of JSON.

Comment: I've really messed up here haven't I lol, these are code snippets I have come across searching for the answer, I rarely use this kind of coding so have no idea how to cross PHP with JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be outputting the timestamps, probably in milliseconds as that's what Javascript supports

```
<?php
    $data = array(
        array(
            mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2014) * 1000,
            -0.5,  
            5.7
        ),
        array(
            mktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2014) * 1000,
            0.4,  
            8.7
        )
    );
?>
```

Now you can just echo it and it will magically turn into a javascript array consisting of arrays

```
data.addRows(<? echo json_encode($data); ?>);
```

Most plugins will accept timestamps, if for some reason you *have* to have date objects, you can do

```
var result = <? echo json_encode($data); ?>;

result.forEach(function(arr) {
    arr[0] = new Date(arr[0]);
});

data.addRows(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in your current code, JSON_ENCODE does absolutely nothing useful but add additional brackets to whole string. Secondly, you have something weird going on with ' symbols in the middle of string. Also, I can't see why should you put that sentence in an array.
Now, assuming that you made a typo and array looks like:

```
$data = array("[new Date(2014, 0),  -.5,  5.7]", "[new Date(2014, 1),   .4,  8.7]");
```

It would be much easier for you to simply loop through it

```
foreach($data as $value){
    echo $value.",";
}
```